# Recalling Session When Browser is closed with Cookies

Tags: php, session-cookies

On login I'm creating the following cookies based on a Remember Me checkbox:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

//creates a cookie if Remember Me is checked
    if(isset($_POST['remember'])){

        $expire_time = time()+86400;
        setcookie("lion123_rmbr", $email, $expire_time);
        setcookie("lion123_rmbr_usrnm", $username, $expire_time);
                }
```

Just above I have the session being created on just the login.

The idea of course is to be able to close the browser, re-open and be able to access the members area without having to login.  In `header.php` I have the following recall:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) || isset($_COOKIE['lion123_rmbr']) || isset($_COOKIE['lion123_rmbr_usrnm'])) {
$userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['username'];
$user_details_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$userLoggedIn'");
$user = mysqli_fetch_array($user_details_query);
}
else{
    header("Location: register.php"); 
}
```

When I open and close the browser, then navigate to members area, the cookies allow for me to do this; however, the user specific data is missing because `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` is not being set on login & of course being terminated once the browser is closed.  So I'm getting the error that `username` is not defined.

I thought that adding the second cookie for username might be the fix...nope :)  Any help on how to activate a user session would be appreciated -  if the only way the session is created is through login, how can this data be passed to activate `$userLoggedIn`?

Thankyou.

Comment: I can't do it now but you should get the cookie and check if that cookie value is in database and if it is just set new session with that cookie value which is connected to user. And first check for cookies after is session set or not. Cuz is the cookie is set you can set session and check is session set.

Comment: the cookies are there yes.  As I said, the cookies allow me to access the index.  Not sure how to activate session based on these cookies as you suggest.  hence the above question.

Comment: What are you setting as session is that cookie value or some other value in users table, cookie need to be connected with some of users values. In case ur session is email and cookie is email you check users table to see if there is use with email as cookie value is if it is set new session as that email. or get some other daata from that user that you use for setting a session. It is not that hard just think a little bit

Comment: Thanks bud, got it.

Comment: No problem :D ..